# Transform counter into final array

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement a counter witch counts notifications from 2 differents collections.
One collections counts the friends request and the other counts the events request. 
And I want to show the number from both collection added. If I just want to show the counter of one collection it works perfectly fine, but not both because is says: "Transform counter into final array" beacause its in an inner class.

Error is in line :  //       receivecount = map.size();

So my code right now look like this

```
 mFirestore.collection("users").document(usid).collection("request").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                int receivecount = 0;


                for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                        String type = (String) doc.getDocument().get("Type");


                        final String otherID = (String) doc.getDocument().get("otherid");

                        mFirestore.collection("users").document(usid).collection("eventeinladung").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                                for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                                    if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                                        Map map = doc.getDocument().getData();
                                 //       receivecount = map.size();




                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        if (type.equals("received")) {
                            receivecount++;

                        }

                    }
                }




                if(receivecount == 0){
                    number.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    numbercontainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    number.setText(String.valueOf(receivecount));

                }



            }
        });
```

Comment: Please add the entire error that you get and the line at which it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change an Immutable value inside an Inner Class. Here is a workaround:

Declare your counter like this:

```
int[] receivecount = {0};
```

then increment the value inside:

```
receivecount[0]++;
```

Comment: It doesnt show me a error but it doesnt work either

Comment: @leonstelzer try to increment it outside of your 'if' condition. and check wether the increment is executed